# Python | Telethon. Как получить ID или Телефон пользователя, который отправил сообщение

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import datetime
import telethon

api_id = 123123123
api_hash = '123123123123'

client = TelegramClient('phoneTest', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=('TestChannel')))
async def normal_handler(event):
    userMessage=event.message.to_dict()['message']
    message_dt = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(message_dt, "Сообщение:", str(userMessage), "от пользователя:")


client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Есть такой простой код, который пока что выводит сообщения. Как узнать телефон/id пользователя который отправил это сообщение?

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=('TestChannel')))
async def normal_handler(event):
    userMessage=event.message.to_dict()['message']
    user=event.message.to_dict()['from_id']['user_id']
    message_dt = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(message_dt, "Сообщение:", str(userMessage), "от пользователя:" + user)
```

Как получить имя пользователя пока не придумал.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Как указал GrDEV необходимо использовать "event.message.to_dickt()". Я лишь дополню, что после этого нужно сделать запрос по полученному id за счет "client.get_enity(PeerUser(user_id))". Из полученных данных можно получить всю необходимую информацию о пользователе.

```
import socks
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.types import PeerUser

api_id = 123456
api_hash = 'qwerty'

client = TelegramClient('bot', api_id, api_hash, proxy=(socks.SOCKS5,'ip', port, 'login', 'password'), system_version='4.10.2')
client.start()

@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def my_event_handler(event):
    user_id = event.message.to_dict()['from_id']['user_id']
    user = await client.get_entity(PeerUser(user_id))
    print(user) #можно выводить user.id, user.first_name и т.д

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Источник: [https://arabic-telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extra/basic/entities.html#:~:text=my_user%20%20%20%20%3D%20client.get_entity(PeerUser(some_id))](https://arabic-telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extra/basic/entities.html#:%7E:text=my_user%20%20%20%20%3D%20client.get_entity(PeerUser(some_id)))